# Get the vale of the inserted row in mysql using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to get the value of the inserted row, so that I can use that row in a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE

    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        //I wan here the value of what was inserted here

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NEW` like below. See [Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) for more information

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET @some_col = NEW.some_col;
END
```

Comment: what will be the value of some_col here? the inserted row? I have never seen the "NEW" keyword

Comment: So if the inserted row has sme_col value as 10 (say) .. @some_col will hold the same value. See edited answer which includes link to the MySQL doc.

Answer (score 1):

If you only inserted one row, [LAST_INSERTED_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)! will retrieve the last ID for you.  You can use this information to get data about that row.

Otherwise, if you inserted more than one row [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39474/find-and-insert-row-to-another-table-using-mysql-trigger) has some information about doing this procedure.

You can also use NEW to do this.